# Native android library compile

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, react-native

I want to compile these code to be android native library. I have tried many techniques and follow many online example and it doesn't work. I will provide the link to the code and explain which part I want to compile.
This the link https://github.com/zyq8709/DexHunter (I want to compile the code in folder called dalvik). If anyone knows how to compile it please help me. thank you

Comment: What I saw, at a quick glance, was in fact Java source files, but what is your actual question?  If you want to use these files in an Android project, then just include them.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Tim biegeleisen. thank you for your answer. the link above contains the customized android ROM but before I can use it I need to compile them and when I compile them I got this error:  Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-14.
jni/libdex/Android.mk:72: C:/Users/HackDX2/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-host-static-library.mk: No such file or directory
jni/dexlist/Android.mk:49: C:/Users/HackDX2/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-host-executable.mk: No such file or directory ......

Answer (score 0):

This code is a part of platform build. If you are lucky, you can compile libdex for device only, but you must ignore the host side. The easiest hack would be to run

```
ndk-build BUILD_HOST_STATIC_LIBRARY=/dev/null BUILD_HOST_EXECUTABLE=/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Final, I have found the solution to compile the above code. I downloaded whole android source by using Ubuntu 16.0.4 and then I modified the specific file which it was changed and replaced it. After I compile whole all the android source code. Finally, I could get a customized ROM which I could use it as I expected. If anyone interested how to download and compile whole the android source code you can follow this link https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements. If you have any problem you can find the solution on google or you can post here so someone including me will respond.